# Unicode not rendering from JSP

Tags: jsp, unicode, utf-8, jsp-tags, dhtmlx

I have implemented a JSP custom tag

```
<mytags:SelectHandler emptyField="false" listName="addneworder.location"/>
```

which will return the list of dropdown option values from properties file in Bengali language in a json format for DhtmlxForm component, it's returning the below output

```
{text: "&#2476;&#2494;&#2455;&#2472;&#2494;&#2472;", value: "INDIA"},{text: "&#2476;&#2494;&#2455;&#2472;&#2494;&#2472;", value: "JAPAN"}
```

But the Bengali Unicode is not rendering in dropdown select list in browser , it's showing as it is.

But a different tag Handler for XML to construct DhtmlxGrid with same Mechanism is working fine.

```
 <cell><![CDATA[<b><mytags:getTranslation key="addneworder"/></b>]]></cell>
```

The above tag returning

```
<cell><![CDATA[<b>&#2472;&#2468;&#2497;&#2472; &#2437;&#2480;&#2509;&#2465;&#2494;&#2480;&#2447;&#2472;&#2509;&#2463;&#2509;&#2480;&#2495;]]></cell>
```

And its Perfectly rendering in Chrome browser
Please Help.